# Macbook Pro 2011 Won't boot

Tags: macbook-pro

I have an early 2011 MacBook Pro 15" that refuses to boot. I have file vault enabled; so I enter my password and then the loading bar completes but never goes anywhere else; occasionally reboots.

I have tried:

- Resetting PRAM
- Resetting SMC
- Internet recovery -- downloads and then reboots same issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: A computer of that age is liable to have a failing hard drive. Can you boot to Recovery and check the drive using Disk Utility there?

Comment: Fsck in single user mode said the drive was ok.

Comment: Do you have an external drive you can install MacOS onto and see if that will boot? That will rule in/out the internal drive.

Comment: Do you remember when it booted successfully? What were your last steps? Did you install any software specially something relating to any Audio?

Comment: Start up using verbose mode, it may show you where in the boot process you are getting hung up on. Are you able to get into safe mode? you can also do the combination of verbose + safe mode for detailed information.